# Outlook Gmail IMAP "too many simultaneous connections"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap

Outlook 2007 with a Gmail account receives the following error message. I have setup multiple Gmail-Outlook-IMAP configurations and have never come across this error before.

"Your IMAP server wants to alert you to the following: Too many simultaneous connections. (Failure)"

The Gmail account is also setup on an iPhone using IMAP.

I have clicked on the "sign out of all other web sessions" under the Gmail website a few times to resolve the issue, however the error keeps coming back!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR81S.png

Comment: Identify how many clients you have connected to this single account.

Comment: How often are you checking e-mail? Are you using the default, or are you checking more often?

Comment: I didn't specify a time to check for new email. Is there a setting for this under IMAP?

Comment: I don't know about Outlook 2007, but There is a setting in Outlook 2011. It doesn't seem to help with the problem for me though. :-(